# Code for taking information I input in one file on sheets and makes it an array so that I can transfer it to another sheet (different ID)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Javascript and Google Script, so please bear with me on this. Below is the code I've written, but it isn't transferring the info.

In my code, I am trying to put the information from one sheet into an array then transfer it to another spreadsheet with sheets for tabs containing changes made in the specific month. I don't need to change any of the info, I just need to move it.

```
function infoTransfer() 
{
  var actveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var byName = actveSheet.getSheetByName("New Item Input Sheet");
  var infoRange = byName.getDataRange();
  var valueRange = infoRange.getValues();
  var infoTable = [];                                                        
  for(var i = 1; i < infoRange.getNumRows(); i++)
  {
   var e = [];
   for(var j = 2; j < infoRange.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++)
    e.push(infoRange.getCell(i,j).editAsText().getText());
   }
   infoTable.push(e);

  var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1QYEwvbPWIZ1sVuOhJ5PZK2KjCQ2waUIBuVX169L-SZU');
  var sh = otherSheet.getSheetId('1505823542')

  sh.getRange(2,1,infoTable.length,infoTable[0].length).setValues(infoTable);  
}
```

Comment: `getValues()` returns an array of all the values, is there a reason you are putting this into another array? Also, is copying the whole sheet from one spreadsheet to another a viable solution?

Comment: -_- oops... must've misread something on the Google site. How should I go about making the arrays? Copying the whole sheet from one to another is not a viable solution.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to remake an array if you're just needing to copy a range of cells from one Spreadsheet to another without editing anything. Can you please share a sanitised copy of your sheet to better understand what you mean?

Comment: Maybe I did not ask the question correctly, sorry. I want to take info from a range that may vary depending upon what is entered, and then I want to move it to another sheet. However, now that I am thinking about it, I think I should make each column an array in case I add other metrics to the other sheet. So, if you can help me understand how to make each column an array, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can get each column as an array and copy it to the new Spreadsheet.*

#### Code:

```js
function copyData() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var byName = activeSheet.getSheetByName("New Item Input Sheet");
  var noOfColumns = byName.getDataRange().getNumColumns();
  var noOfRows = byName.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var arrayOfColumns = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++) {
    arrayOfColumns[i] = byName.getRange(1, i + 1, noOfRows, 1);
  }
  var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('destination-spreadsheet-id');
  var sheet = destinationSheet.getSheetByName('sheet-name');

  for (var i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(1, i + 1, noOfRows, 1).setValues(arrayOfColumns[i].getValues());
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Method `Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)